# How to deal with Fractional Max Pool error using Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to use the Tensorflow `fraction_max_pool_op`. The model is being constructed as expected, but when the training starts I get the following error:

```
tensorflow/core/kernels/fractional_max_pool_op.cc:352] Check failed: 
input_backprop_index >= 0 && input_backprop_index < num_total_inputs 
Invalid input backprop index: -1, 395010
```

What should I fix to deal with that? What additional info could help you to help me?

Comment: What's the pooling ratio you're using on the batch and channel dimensions? Remember that they can't exceed 1.0, according to the documentation: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/fractional_max_pool

Comment: Thank you, Pranav Vempati. I defined my fraction max pool layer using the following code: `unpool1 = tf.nn.fractional_max_pool(dconv1_4, pooling_ratio=[1.0, .2, .2, 1.0]).output`.